# Hidden sort display in iOS app from tapping post tag

Tags: bug, status-completed, search, ios-app

Under the search bar is a gray bar that is supposed to show the current sort method. That bar is covered by another gray bar without a label.

> [image]

Pulling down beyond the top reveals the top-secret useful label.

> [image]

### Steps to reproduce:

- open a post
- tap a tag from the post
- profit

### Details:

- 0.1.29 SE App
- iOS 7.1 (11D167)

Comment: Your battery is dying man.

Comment: I am taking a look at this

Comment: @Arie, edited with steps that work for me, but it looks like your comment changed, so maybe you found it yourself after all

Comment: I see those steps took heavy toll on your battery! ;-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We were accidentally showing two headers in this case, one which was covering the useful one.

This will be **fixed in version 0.1.30**.